# How to handle a NFS Mount only in my local Network

Tags: linux, networking, nfs

i have in my Local Network a NAS with NFS Shares. How to handle that ma Laptop connect automagically to the NFS Share? I tried a Entry in the fstab File but when i outside the local network my Client needs up to 5 Minutes to boot because he is waiting for the NFS Timeout.

Is there any Solution that detect that my Laptop is on the local Network and mount than?

Thanks

Comment: In the options field of the line in fstab, try adding the `bg` option. This should minimize boot delays when the share isn't accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to execute a command on boot is to put it into `/etc/cron.d/nfsmount` with the content:

```
@reboot root /bin/sleep 7 && /bin/ping -c 1 -W 1 10.0.0.2 > /dev/null && /bin/mount /foo
```

On `reboot` it wait `7` seconds, then do one `ping` with a timeout in `1` second, and if it went good then `mount` NFS with the parameters specified in `/etc/fstab`.

In `/etc/fstab` you should have the option `noauto`:

```
10.0.0.2:/foo /foo nfs noauto 0 0
```

If you have `systemd` you might want to look at `systemd.automount`.

Comment: wow! this works!!! many many many many many thanks. you are my hero

Answer (score 0):

you can give a shot to monit that will monitor the nfs mount then can take action.

from the [manual](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Filesystem) :

> ```
> CHECK FILESYSTEM <unique name> PATH <string>
> ```
>
> path is the path to the device/disk, mount point or NFS/CIFS/FUSE connection string. If
>   the filesystem becomes unavailable, Monit will call the service's
>   start method if defined. If Monit runs in passive mode or the start
>   method is not defined, Monit will just send an alert on error.

For example you can use a rule like this one :

```
check filesystem nfsDisk1 with path nfs://<yournfsexport>
       if does not exist then exec "ping host && mount..."
```

if ping fails will not try to mount

Note that you need to remove your mount from fstab to let monit handle the mount

Then to optimise you can do something similar for the detection of your local network and then make your first rule depends on it

Have fun with monit